# how to index a column in MySQL within "CREATE TABLE" command

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Is there a way to index the non-unique email column below within the CREATE TABLE command?

Instead of this:

```
CREATE TABLE addresses (
    phone_number VARCHAR(12) PRIMARY KEY,
    email TINYTEXT,
);
ALTER TABLE addresses ADD INDEX (email);
```

something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE addresses (
    phone_number VARCHAR(12) PRIMARY KEY,
    email TINYTEXT INDEX,
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easily:

```sql
CREATE TABLE addresses (
    phone_number VARCHAR(12) PRIMARY KEY,
    email TINYTEXT,
    INDEX index_email (email)
);
```

[(Source)](https://www.w3processing.com/index.php?subMenuLoad=SQL/Definition/IndexCreate.php)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
CREATE TABLE addresses (
    phone_number VARCHAR(12) PRIMARY KEY,
    email TINYTEXT,
    INDEX ix (email)
);
```

By default, all indexes are not unique.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the key length for text key.
Try:

```
CREATE TABLE `addresses`(
phone_number VARCHAR(12),
email TINYTEXT,
PRIMARY KEY `phone_number`(`phone_number`) ,
KEY `email` (`email`(255)));
```

`KEY` and `INDEX` are synonyms  in `MySQL`

Answer (score 1):

This creates and index named ix_email on the column email at table creation time.

```
CREATE TABLE addresses (
    phone_number VARCHAR(12) PRIMARY KEY,
    email TINYTEXT,
    INDEX ix_email (email)
);
```